# How do I replace values in data column according to dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science

I need to replace the values in a column of my dataset with values that refer to the values with the same name in dictionary. 
So my data looks like this (don't pay attention on column names):

```
data = data[['A?',
       'B',...,]]
```

And the dictionary looks like ths:

```
felt_index = {
  "First opt": 1,
  "Second opt": 1,
  "Third opt": 0.72
}
```

I want that instead of my column looks like this:

| A? | ... |
| --- | --- |
| First opt | ... |
| Second opt | ... |
| Third opt | ... |

It would have look like this:

| A? | ... |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ... |
| 1 | ... |
| 0.72 | ... |

I've tried some solutions and it didn't work out.
The last thing I tried is:

```
for val in data[['A?']]:        
        data[['A']][val] = felt_index.get(data[['A?']][val])
```

And I got this error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'
```

I can't figure t out how to solve it:( Please, help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pandas.DataFrame.replace`:

```
new_df = df.replace({"A?": felt_index})
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
     A?  ...
0  1.00  ...
1  1.00  ...
2  0.72  ...
```

From the official doc of `pandas.DataFrame.replace`:

> For a DataFrame, nested dictionaries, e.g.,             `{'a': {'b': np.nan}}`, are read as follows: look in column 'a' for the value 'b' and replace it with NaN.

If you want to replace those not in a dictionary:

```
# Sample
           A?  ...
0   First opt  ...
1  Second opt  ...
2   Third opt  ...
3     Non opt  ...

df["A?"] = df["A?"].map(felt_index).replace({np.nan: None})
```

Output:

```
     A?  ...
0   1.0  ...
1   1.0  ...
2  0.72  ...
3  None  ...
```

Note that since you want `None`, it requires `replace` with `dict`. If you want a specific value, use `fillna` instead:

```
df["A?"] = df["A?"].map(felt_index).fillna("NO!")
```

Output:

```
     A?  ...
0   1.0  ...
1   1.0  ...
2  0.72  ...
3   NO!  ...
```

Comment: It worked, thanks! But I also need to replace values that are not in a dictionary with None.

Comment: @Yamobura Check my update ;)